# Trying to access to a virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm getting this error:

> [Thu Nov 10 17:53:58 2011] [error] [client 95.240.108.197] File does
>   not exist: /var/www/aib/web/aib

I don't know why it's looking for that file. I expected it looks for /var/www/aib/web/app.php.

This is my virtual-host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 173.203.58.251:80>
  ServerName tirengarfio
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/aib/web"
  DirectoryIndex app.php

  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/aib.localhost-error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/aib.localhost-access.log" common
  TransferLog "/var/log/apache2/aib.localhost-transfer.log"

  <Directory "/var/www/aib/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: What address are you requesting in your browser?

Comment: Are there any `.htaccess` files in the document root? You have AllowOverride set to All, so perhaps there's some additional configuration that we aren't seeing.

Comment: If you create a helloworld.txt file in the document root and access it through your browser, does it work? Or do you get a similar error message?
Side note: how do you not have a TLD on your servername? Does apache accept that as correct syntax? I ask because I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the URL you are trying to load, it's a bit difficult to narrow down the cause.

I usually see these type of errors when Apache is trying to load a directory as if it's a file.

In your case, it looks like Apache thinks /var/www/aib/web/aib is a file, not a directory.  This means the URL trying to be loaded is incorrect.  Usually missing the trailing '/'.

To hit /var/www/aib/web/app.php you have to point your browser to http://tirengarfio/app.php

If you want apache to use app.php as the default index page you have to adjust your [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) setting.

Comment: Thanks @David, I just was trying to access directly to the IP of my VPS (http://173.34.243.32). I turn on the computer today and there is no more that error..